# Can i fire long click event for a view programmatically?

Tags: android, click

can I fire long click event for a view programmatically ? I know there is performClick() function for firing click event but I'm looking for long click event

Comment: Try to implement longClickListener interface in your activity or fragment it would be something like this : `MyActivity extends Activity implements onLongClickListener`  then you can override onLongClick method that requires View as parameter and just programatically pass your View object to that method and call it.

Comment: Btw are you trying to executing code that is inside long click ? If yes just put it into method and call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
view.performLongClick();
```

Answer (score 3):

view.performLongClick(); It exists for me...

Comment: See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performLongClick%28%29

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void longClickView(View v) {

    final int viewWidth = v.getWidth();
    final int viewHeight = v.getHeight();

    final float x = viewWidth / 2.0f;
    final float y = viewHeight / 2.0f;

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    v.onTouchEvent(event);

    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final int touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(v.getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
            x + touchSlop / 2, y + touchSlop / 2, 0);
    v.onTouchEvent(event);

    v.postDelayed(() -> {
        long eventTime2 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        MotionEvent event2 = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime2, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
        v.onTouchEvent(event2);
    }, (long) (ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() * 1.5f));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


                //do your stuff here

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thats how you do long click in android. or implements `onLongClickListener` with your parent class then add unimplemented method

with your view.

view.setOnLongClickListener(this);

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built in function like `performClick()`. So you will have to implement the system yourself.

You can listen to `onTouchListener`. Then with the help of `event.ACTION_DOWN` and `event.ACTION_UP` determine if the touch is Long key press and perform the action accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: view.performClick(), view.performLongClick() are available. Have a look on View class